# programatically change style (padding) of a column in ASP.NET GridView

Tags: .net, asp.net, css, gridview

I need to change padding for one column in ASP.NET GridView, while all other CSS atributes defined in external CSS file should be left untouched. How can I do it?

Thanks in advance!

Update:
Below is my code that solved the problem:

```
protected void gvwMaster_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Cells[0].Attributes.Add("style", "padding:0");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tap into RowCommand event, which has e.Row.Cells, which you can change the styles for the cell (should have a styles collection or a CssClass property).  I don't think each field (which translates to the column) has a CSS style setting...