# displaying space padded records in asp.net gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview control where I am displaying records from a dataset. The dataset contains records that are space padded as needed. I am trying to follow the solution in this post [programatically change style (padding) of a column in ASP.NET GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2342232/165694)

However, when I display them in the gridview, the records show left aligned.

How can I display space padded records?

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvCustomer" Visible="false"
    Width="350px" CellSpacing="1" ClientIDMode="Static" CellPadding="2" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="gvCustomer_OnRowDataBound"
    ViewStateMode="Enabled" EmptyDataText="">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerName" ControlStyle-Width="225px" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="Customers" />
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you'll have to do is change your `BoundField` to be a `TemplateField`, and use a `RowDataBound` event to replace all spaces with `&nbsp;`. HTML does not deal with spaces in the way you would like, which is why you'll need the non-breaking-space (`&nbsp;`) character.

Or if you really would like to use a `BoundField`, modify your sql query to replace spaces with `&nbsp;` and bind.

Comment: +1 for the BoundField solution.  TemplateField can be a pain if you're doing a lot of them...  (unless you generate them programmatically)

Comment: I did modify the SQL and replaced the spaces with &nbsp; but now the gridview displays "&nbsp;&nbsp;CustomerA"..... however, I changed the "&nbsp;" to straight hyphens.... just to distinguish Parent from Child. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are only setting the Header's alignment. You want to add:

`ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"`

to the `asp:BoundField` control

Comment: I believe he has a string padded first with spaces, such as "    Name" that he wants to display in his gridview as such, not left/center/right aligned.

Comment: I'm confused @DotNetRookie: your question said "However, when I display them in the gridview, the records show left aligned." So the assumption was that the padding worked, but the alignment did not. What are the spaces saved in the dataset as? &nbsp; or just space?

Comment: @Charx.. the dataset returns "<space bar>CustomerA"... not "nbsp;nbsp;nbsp;CustomerA"

Answer (score 0):

HTML does not deal with whitespace in the way you appear to think it does.  If you have multiple spaces between text or tags, the browser will ignore any extra whitespace.

In other words, the following will render on screen in exactly the same way

```
<b>Hello                     World</b>
<b>Hello World</b>
```

So, what I would suggest is you replace each of the leading spaces with the "no breaking space" character `&nbsp;` which the browser *will* take notice of.

Unfortunately what I can't do is give you an example of how you would do that with the `<BoundField>` in a `GridView`... as I simply have never used it, and so cannot comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply your `css` class, do this

```
            <asp:BoundField>
            <ItemStyle CssClass="MyCSSClass" />
            </asp:BoundField>
```

Answer (score 0):

on a boundfield mark it as HtmlEncode = false and use

```
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

to enter 3 spaces