# how to use space inside string

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview

i want use space inside string, i use this code:

```
var lst = Article.Select(a => new {a.ID, Name = "     " + a.Name}).ToList();
gv.DataSource = lst.ToList();
gv.DataBind();
```

but its not working, with this code display name = " "Name.

and use this code:

```
var lst = Article.Select(a => new {a.ID, Name = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + a.Name}).ToList();
gv.DataSource = lst.ToList();
gv.DataBind();
```

and with this code display name = "     "Name.

please help me

Edit:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<Columns>
...
<asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ReadOnly="True" ItemStyle-Width="300px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"></asp:BoundField>
...
</asp:GridView>
```

Edit2:

Answer:

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924058/asp-net-binding-to-gridview-strips-some-space-whitespace-characters)

[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12938369/displaying-space-padded-records-in-asp-net-gridview)

Thank you to all.

Comment: thx. but its not working

Comment: I think the issue here is that the text is being outputted to HTML which doesn't care about additional whitespace. If multiple `&nbsp;` aren't working, then you may need to apply CSS margins/padding.

Comment: what is gv? can you control its padding?

Comment: gv has gridview control.

Answer (score 2):

will this work?

[string constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w.aspx) that constructs a string from a character a `repeat` count:

```
var lst = Article.Select(a => new {a.ID, Name = new string(' ', 8) + a.Name})
                 .ToList();
```

**UPDATE 1**

set property, `HtmlEncode=False`

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HtmlEncode="False" />
```

and enclosed the value with `<pre>` tag

```
var lst = Article.Select(a => new {a.ID, Name = "<pre>      </pre>" + a.Name})
                 .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming the gv is an asp.net gridview control and that all your whitespace is being merged when displayed in a browser.

So, try something like this

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Name">
<ItemStyle CssClass="NameCol" />
</asp:BoundField>
```

and in your css

```
..NameCol
{
padding-left:50px;
}
```

Comment: A q&d option might be `<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="right" />`

Comment: space number varies and I have to use my linq. please help me for use space in linq code

Comment: what determines the number of spaces you are wanting to insert?

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample way

```
a.Name.ToString().PadLeft(10," ")
```

- **Must use ToString()**

**Edit** Try this

```
a.Name.PadLeft(10,' ')
```

Comment: i use code but ERROR: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String PadLeft(Int32, Char)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: FWIW there's really no reason to use that overload if you're just padding spaces.